# How to set row names for list of matrix or data frame?

Tags: r

I have list, which consists of data frame in every element of it. I want to set one of the column of evey data frame as rows name for it. but when I do this, I lose the dimension of my data.

Here is example of my data and my effort:

```
> ismr2[[1]][1:4,]
  mature           ID        RPM
1 mature MIMAT0000062 49791.5560
2 mature MIMAT0000063 92858.1285
3 mature MIMAT0000064 10418.8532
4 mature MIMAT0000065   404.7618
>
```

My effort ;

```
ismr3<-lapply(ismr2, function(x){ row.names(x)<-as.character(x$ID) })


> dim(ismr3[[1]])
NULL
>
```

dimension of first element of list before row.name operation is :

```
> dim(ismr2[[1]])
[1] 447   3
```

would someone help me to solve this probelm ?

Comment: You need a return value in your anonymous function: `ismr3<-lapply(ismr2, function(x){ row.names(x)<-as.character(x$ID); x})`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm adding @Roland's answer here so the question appears answered.

```
ismr3 <- lapply(ismr2, function(x){ row.names(x)<-as.character(x$ID); x})
```

The important part is that the function inside lapply actually returns the value to be added to the list. With just the `row.names<-` assignment, the value returned from that is just the row names themselves. So because each assignment was returning a character vector, you were not creating an object that had a `dim()` attribute. (Atomic vectors have `length`, not `dim`).